# NiFi not starting on Windows

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am getting this error on starting NiFi.

2021-07-27 11:48:16,955 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read pid file

and

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name

I have tried

- using cmd window in Administrator mode
- Changed to http settings instead of https
- changed ports
- set PATH  JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME
- tries running on windows server and work desktop

when I run  "run-nifi.bat"

i get:

```
    2021-07-27 15:22:00,668 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Starting Apache NiFi...
2021-07-27 15:22:00,668 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Working Directory: C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0
2021-07-27 15:22:00,669 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin\java.exe -classpath C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.30.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jetty-schemas-3.1.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.30.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.30.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-api-1.14.0.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-framework-api-1.14.0.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-nar-utils-1.14.0.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-properties-1.14.0.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-property-utils-1.14.0.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-runtime-1.14.0.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-server-api-1.14.0.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-stateless-api-1.14.0.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\nifi-stateless-bootstrap-1.14.0.jar;C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true -Xmx512m -Xms512m -Dcurator-log-only-first-connection-issue-as-error-level=true -Djavax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -Dzookeeper.admin.enableServer=false -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol -Dnifi.properties.file.path=C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\.\conf\nifi.properties -Dnifi.bootstrap.listen.port=49291 -Dapp=NiFi -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\\logs org.apache.nifi.NiFi
2021-07-27 15:22:00,898 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read pid file C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\run\nifi.pid; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2021-07-27 15:22:00,900 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Failed to set permissions so that only the owner can read status file C:\NiFi\NIFI-1~1.0-B\NIFI-1~1.0\bin\..\run\nifi.status; this may allows others to have access to the key needed to communicate with NiFi. Permissions should be changed so that only the owner can read this file
2021-07-27 15:22:00,902 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 12948
```

And then it closes.

any ideas what to try next.

Comment: Only Java 8 or 11 are supported

Comment: I am on 1.8 java

Comment: Your error message contains `jdk-16.0.2`

Comment: i run:  U:\>java -version, then I get:  
java version "1.8.0_301"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_301-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.301-b09, mixed mode)

Comment: I have restarted my computer and now shows as 1.8 in error message

Comment: check the nifi-app.log and nifi-bootstrap.log files in the log dir for any errors. Double check that you definitely can't reach the Nifi ui in your browser...

Comment: Thank you for your help, in nifi-app.log: 2021-07-27 15:25:33,561 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
org.apache.nifi.web.NiFiCoreException: Unable to start Flow Controller, ------- also I can not reach 127.0.0.1:8083

Comment: @MorganHayes - Facing same problem here. Were you able to find solution to it?

Comment: no, I moved on to another solution. not using nifi